# Computing convex hull of a bunch of circles

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis

I am stuck on the following question

```
Let S be a set of n (possibly intersecting) unit circles in the plane.
Design a O(nlog(n)) algorithm to compute the convex hull of S and
returns an array in which stores the coordinates of the centers
of the units disks that are on the border of the convex hull.

No circles will be the same and no three circles will be colinear.
```

This is the last question and the only one I don't know how to tackle. I understand convex hull algorithms such as the gift-wrapping one.

Any pointers  in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute the convex hull of the centers.
Since all the circles ('disks' would have been a better and equivalent formulation) have the same radius, the convex hull of the circles is the Minkowski sum of
{the convex hull of the centers} and {the unit disk}.

Comment: Seems like this is a bit trivial... we are just computing the convex hull of the given set of points (which are the centers) using Graham Scan..

Comment: Yes, it is trivial. But only **after** you prove that the convex hull of the disks is equal to the given Minkowski sum.  I am sure your 'prof' will want you to prove this equality.

Comment: We actually haven't learned about Minkowski sums yet. Is there another way that you know of?

Comment: You can get a compass and straightedge and paper.
After working through a few examples,
you may be able to show
that the situation is trivial without
using the full power of Minkowski sums.